# What is the meaning of symbol $ in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the `$` sign in jQuery stand for?

Comment: you could make the title a wee bit more descriptive, instead of just looking like a couple of category tags

Comment: it's a fine question for jquery noobs such as myself.  I cobbled together some jquery pages by cutting and pasting from the internet, and it was the first question I had about what I was doing.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The jQuery object :)

From the jQuery documentation:

> By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

So, using `$("#id"`) or `jQuery("#id")` is the same.

Comment: Hi, @Andrea i don't know whether i'm asking correct question or not, i'm new to jQuery. Can we replace that $ with any other symbol? and if possible, how?

Comment: @Hulk you can use `noConflit()` to replace it .

Answer (score 50):

Strange but true, you can use "$" as a function name in JavaScript.  It is shorthand for jQuery().  Which you can use if you want.  jQuery can be ran in compatibility mode if another library is using the $ already.  Just use jQuery.noConflict().  $ is pretty commonly used as a selector function in JS.

In jQuery the $ function does much more than select things though.

1. You can pass it a selector to get a
   collection of matching elements from the DOM.
2. You can pass
   it a function to run when the
   document is ready (similar to
   body.onload() but better).
3. You can pass it a string of HTML to turn
   into a DOM element which you can
   then inject into the document.
4. You can pass it a DOM element or
   elements that you want to wrap with
   the jQuery object.

Here is the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: You know, this REALLY should be the right answer for this question... I can't believe all those joke-y answers got all the up-votes.

Comment: Agree with reedvoid's comments. It is a reflection on the state of affairs in Javascript programming. That said, the more precise link now that answers the question is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: If $ is a function, then how are we calling the method noConflict() on it? That would have been possible if $ was an object, not function.

Comment: @dk49 In JavaScript, functions can have properties too. Try this: function Person() {}; Person.city = 'Missoula'; console.log(Person.city)

Comment: For more evidence try `typeof $` which will ouput "Function". ;)

Answer (score 34):

It is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). It is not specific only to jQuery; other libraries use it as well. You can look for a full-details article about the use of dollar sign in JavaScript [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170212234654/http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign).

Comment: Well, I liked the term *syntactic sugar*.
Thank for that :)

Comment: How is this an answer? From this I learned that the '$' sign in jQuery stands for "syntactic sugar". And the linked article talks at length about the hows and the why, without answering it concisely. The next answer by @andrea does the job in three words.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to know why is that $ symbol chosen to represent the library, not on what really means, which is kinda obvious and documented

Comment: that link doesnt work anymore, the one that you said explains in detail $

Comment: @user734028 I changed the link to a cached one, please check now

Answer (score 30):

As said in other answers $ is a shortcut to the jQuery function.

Some JavaScript libraries uses $ too (example: prototype). To avoid conflict with those other libraries jQuery provides jQuery.noConflict() function. Calling this function the control of the $ variable goes back to the other library that first implemented it. Doing this to use jQuery you can't do this $('div.someClass') anymore, instead jQuery('div.someClass').

Alternatively can do this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery.ready(function($) {
   // use $ for jQuery
}

//use $ for the other library
```

When writing plugins to avoid problems with the usage of noConflict you can pass 'jQuery' to a function:

```
function($) {

//use $ writing your plugin

}(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 9):

$ is simply a function called jQuery. It is how you access all of the functionality in the jQuery lib.

You can find it here: http://docs.jquery.com/%24

Answer (score 7):

It's short for jQuery. The object where all the jQuery functionality live.

Answer (score 5):

The $ is syntactic sugar like @Elzo mentioned. Nobody actually answered your question though. The $ is shorthand in jQuery for `window.jQuery`, so you don't have to type it every single time.

Answer (score 4):

$ is just another variable. In the case of jQuery this references the function jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

A $ sign to define/access jQuery

Answer (score 1):

$ sign to define/access jQuery
$(selector).action()

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jQuery library file.

//Expose jQuery and $ identifiers.

```
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

Global $ points to jQuery.