# Broken Menu Styling After Adding New Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, mootools

I have dropdown menus that look like this:

[image]

However, I wanted a div element to stick the top of a page at a certain scroll range, so I added this code in the head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $el = $('.fixedElement');
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1437 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){
        $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'});
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1437 && $el.css('position') != 'absolute'){
        $('.fixedElement').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '1437px'});
    }
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

`.fixedElement` is defined in my `CSS` file, and then referenced with

```
<div class="fixedElement">
```

Now, my dropdown menus look like this:

[image]

When I comment out the new `javascript`, the menus go back to normal.

Any ideas on how to make my new `javascript` work with my dropdown menus?

Thanks!

EDIT:

One console error pertaining to the dropdown `javascript` is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getElements'
```

That is referencing this line:

```
var links = $(this.options.id).getElements('a');
```

In this javascript: [MenuMatic](http://code.google.com/p/erptrojas-caja-chica/source/browse/trunk/+erptrojas-caja-chica+--username+miguel.cornejo/MenuMatic/MenuMatic_0.68.3-source.js?r=2)

When I comment out the new `javascript` the error disappears and my menus come back!

Comment: @Utkanos 
The one error I have pertaining to the dropdown javascript is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getElements'`

That is referencing this line:
`var links = $(this.options.id).getElements('a');`

Comment: Well then that's coming from another script, since the bit you posted makes no reference to `getElements()`.

Comment: Right, the error is in the dropdown script. I'm using [MenuMatic](http://code.google.com/p/erptrojas-caja-chica/source/browse/trunk/+erptrojas-caja-chica+--username+miguel.cornejo/MenuMatic/MenuMatic_0.68.3-source.js?r=2) for that code because I'm not very familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

My dropdown `javascript` was using the MooTools library, while my sticky div was using jQuery.

jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery", so the line

```
var links = $(this.options.id).getElements('a');
```

referencing `javascript` from the MooTools library throws an error because jQuery has overwritten the definition for "$"

This conflict is solved by inserting

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

before my jQuery script and replacing all of the "$" in my jQuery script with "jQuery"

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

See also:

[jQuery and other libraries, and the usage of '$'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158606/jquery-and-other-libraries-and-the-usage-of)

[What is the meaning of symbol $ in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery/1050433#1050433)