# $ and $() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can understand that `$()` is jQuery object but what is `$`?  for example `$.fn.each` and `$.each`.

I am confused here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the $ in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-in-jquery)

Comment: Try to keep in mind, too, that all functions are objects in JavaScript. $ is the jQuery object which is also a function, and $() calls that function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` and `jQuery` are a function which contains properties.

The jQuery source contains the line

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery
```

This sets `$` and `jQuery` to refer to the same object (which is a function)

The source also sets properties of this object, like

```
jQuery.each = function(...) { ... };
```

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript) should explain it, specifically this comment: Note: By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery".

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an alias for `jQuery`, which is simply a function. When you do `$(...)`, you are calling that function. Functions are also objects in JavaScript, so they can have properties -- `$.fn` and `$.each` are just properties of this object.

Answer (score 0):

> In jQuery, the dollar sign $ is simply
>   shorthand for jQuery. Because a $() 
>                  function is very common in JavaScript libraries, conflicts
>   could arise if more
>                  than one of these libraries is being used in a given
>   page. We can avoid such 
>                  conflicts by replacing every instance of $ with jQuery in our
>   custom jQuery 
>                  code.

Extracted text from Learning Jquery .

I think this will be useful to you . :)