# What is "$" in jquery framework?

Tags: jquery, variables, object, alias

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the $ in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-in-jquery)

We know that **$** is an alias of **jQuery**, while using jQuery javascript framework.

But internally what $ is ?

I mean whether it is an object, function or other thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ is a function object in jQuery.  It can take a number of different types of parameters or methods.  That's why you will see things like:

```
$("#content")
```

In that use, it's just a function - identical to:

```
jQuery("#content")
```

In this example, it returns an object that contains both the collection of DOM items matching the passed in CSS string and has a whole bunch of methods that let you operate on that collection of items it returned such as:

```
var html = $("#content").html()
```

to get the innerHTML of that DOM object.

It is usually used like a function `$(params)`, but can also has methods as an object `$.get()`.

But, most of all `$` is just a symbol for a function object that also has methods.  It could be called `foo` or anything else so it's not anything unusual in Javascript.

Comment: Not *just* a function. E.g. you can do `$.get('myhtmlpage.html', myCallBack);` which would not be possible unless `$` were also an object. See @Steffen's answer.

Comment: Since all functions are also objects in JS, I called it a function.  In any case, I've enhanced my choice of wording.

Answer (score 2):

$ is just and alias. Its same as jQuery Object. That is its reference to jQuery Object.

Comment: This answer is just repeating parts of the question. Why are people upvoting it?

Answer (score 1):

$ is an object, just like jQuery is. Besides, all objects in javascript are functions and all functions are objects.

Comment: To understand recursion, one has to first understand recursion.

Comment: +1 this is the only completely right answer so far.

Comment: @Cularis - This is what they call out of the box solution.

Answer (score 0):

`$` is a variable in exactly the same way that `jQuery` is a variable. And its value is a function.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a pointer to the JQuery prototype function.