# Are jQuery utility functions preferable to ordinary function definitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This jQuery course](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/jquery-air-captains-log) recommends defining your own jQuery utility functions as a good way to organise your code.

But it doesn't really explain why. So, why is writing code like:

```
$.highlightResults = function(seats) {
  // 
}
$.highlightResults('/.seating-chart a');
```

preferable to simply:

```
function highlightResults(seats) { 
 //
}
highlightResults('/.seating-chart a');
```

Is the course wrong, or is there a good reason to write it this way?

Comment: To not clutter the global "namespace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ is a jQuery function object or alias of jQuery.(More precisely jQuery function and every function in javascript is an object). see [What is the meaning of symbol $ in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)

```
 $.highlightResults => highlightResults is a property of jQuery object.
```

While defining any function as a property of jQuery function object, you can access
jQuery function object and all associated properties/functions of jQuery by 'this' inside your function.

Take a simple example.

```
$.property1 ='a';
$.property2 ='b';
$.highlightResults = function(){
                                 var concat = this.property1 + this.property2;
                               };
```

It's all about code organization and behavior.

While if you define

```
function highlightResults(){xyxyxy;}
```

it's not a property of jQuery function object and sits in **GLOBAL space**

Comment: Isn't $ the jQuery function? Of course it's a Function object, but "jQuery object" sounds like "jQuery wrapper instance".

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense now.