# what does $ mean here in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following

```
var obj = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5 };
    $.each(obj, function(i, val) {
       console.log(val);
    });
```

what does $ mean here? Is $ an object?

Comment: Every function in JavaScript is also an object. The `$` in your code refers to the jQuery function, and therefore to the jQuery function *as an object*. The way jQuery is written is such that various utility methods are exposed as properties of the object (that is, properties of the function object).

Comment: $ stands for dollars, or in other words mula, cash, money etc. and it's always an object no matter how much you got!

Comment: +1 nice question as it is not as obvious (not sure how answer gets +5 but question only +1). In addition to `Xion`'s answer, see this documentation which mentions this too: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ As stated at the top of the documentation: `Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of symbol $ in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is an alias for `jQuery` object/function. It's acts as a namespace under which all jQuery functions are stored.

Answer (score 1):

$ stands for jQuery function/object, you can find good discussion over [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

> jQuery() — which can also be written as $() — searches through the DOM
>   for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new
>   jQuery object that references these elements..

-jQuery Site

Comment: That would be the jQuery function, or `$()`, not the jQuery object namespaced `$`, used as an object in `$.each()` even though they are basically the same thing, `$.each()` does not search for elements matcing a selector!

Answer (score 0):

`$` is referring to the jQuery function.

In JavaScript, a function is a special kind of object.

You can create a function and add properties to it like any other object.

```
var $ = function(message) { alert(message); };

$.prop1 = 'val1';
$.prop2 = 'val2';

$("Hello world");

alert($.prop2);

alert($ instanceof Object);   /* This will be "true" */
alert($ instanceof Function); /* This will be "true" */
```