# "$.()" in jQuery. What is its meaning?

Tags: jquery

reading a tutorial of Ajax, I found a jQuery line like this:

```
$.get("www.nameurl.com/...", function(resp) {
    alert("The reply is " + resp);
})
```

I'm not going to ask you explanations about Ajax and the particular meaning of this lines.

What I don't understand is that jQuery input "$.get()".

I usually read or use $(document), $(window), $(".classname") etc, but I never used a kind of formulation like $.get().

Can you provide me some explanations?

Comment: see:: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: This is just how jQuery namespaces its functions by default. Everything lives under the `$` object.

Comment: Its just a variable name defined for a jQuery object. It has lots of useful methods for you :)

Comment: `.get()` is a method from the jQuery ($) object. e.g. $.methodName

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

The `$.[functionName]` construct is used for jQuery utility functions and other jQuery functions that do not perform operations on a set of selected elements.  You will find others such as `$.map()`, `$.each()`, etc.

To see other functions using this syntax checkout the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/)

Comment: Perhaps "...is used for jQuery functions that aren't tied to a jQuery set." I didn't think "utility function" was incorrect in any significant way, but...

Answer (score 0):

This method fetches data using HTTP GET Method, It accepts few parameters for executing this method .

```
 jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

your `$get.()` load data from the server using a **HTTP GET** request. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

**url**

Type: String
A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.

**data**

A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

**success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**

A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

**dataType**

The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html).

Its actually a shorthand for **Ajax function** which is equivalent to -[Here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) .

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

> .get()

Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object

Without a parameter, `.get()` returns an array of all of the elements:
[Here](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2)

Comment: This is not OP asking for?  OP wants to know what is `jQuery.()`

Comment: @user1671639 Well it's same fetches data using `HTTP GET` method .