# Add functions to $ (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe this is simple for some of you but how to add

`$.functionName(args)`

I've read and tried with `jQuery.extend` and with `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.alertSometing = function(param) {
  alert(param);
};
```

But when I run

```
  $('.button').on('click', $.alertSometing('something'));
```

Returns this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.alertSometing is not a function(anonymous
>   function)

This is my code: http://jsbin.com/kuxomofoka/edit?html,js,console,output

Can someone explain me how to achive that or explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The idea of extending jQuery is that you'll be able to call your own methods (like your `alertSomething`) on an existing jQuery context. For example: `$('.button').alertSomething()`. For a start, the `this` keyword in your function will refer to each element in the context.

Comment: but I want to use my $.alertSomething() outside an element, like jquery.cookie does $.cookie('name', 'value');

Comment: What is your expected behavior? what should happen when the button is clicked?

Comment: @Hiero, Don't use `$.fn` then. Your specific problem here is that you're not passing a function callback to the `on('click')` event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is [just a regular object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery).

Like all JS objects, unless frozen (it's not) - you can just add properties to it:

```
$.alertSomething = function(message){ alert(message); };
```

Similarly for any object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.alertSomething = function(message){ alert(message); };
```

In general, if your code does not have anything in particular to do with jQuery, I warmly recommend you do not add it to the jQuery object and instead put it on your own namespace or in a module. This helps avoid naming conflicts. Putting things on `$` or `$.fn` is useful to make plugins.

Comment: I want to write this as a plugin, but I dont want to use $myDiv.myPlugin, I just want to use $.myPlugin(something), as jquery.cookie does, so its ok to add proprieties to $?

Comment: @Hiero yes, it is perfectly fine to add properties to $, this is what other plugins do too.

Comment: Although to be fair, in OP's specific usecase, this fails. If you plug this in directly to OP's code, his code won't call `alert()` on every click, it would call it once. It's more OP problem than yours though. It's worth mentioning.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha this is a community wiki answer, by all means go for it.

Answer (score -2):

Try passing anonymous function as callback. And then use your previously created jquery method.

```
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    $(this).alertSomething('something');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

First , jquery functions(like 'on','click'..) are different with javascript function.

So in your case , should be declare like :

$('.button').alertSometing('something');

Comment: jQuery functions are absolutely not different from JavaScript functions. jQuery is a JavaScript library, not the other way around.

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library , yes you're right . But the jquery function has a little bit different with javascript function . Different in the way using . In javascript how can you override onclick event ?