# What does the $ sign in javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to javascript and I am looking very often on the internet for guides and explanation. The one thing that keeps on coming back is this $ sign in the code. I can not get my head around what this means. Is this only used in an older version of js?

Here is an example of code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //initial
       $('#content').load('content/index.php');
    });
       //handle menu clicks 
       $('#Kevin li a').click(function(){
           alert("hi");
       });
    });
```

Comment: `$` is just a variable identifier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names and in this case it is being used by jQuery, based on the example you have posted.

Comment: Try this in your console: `var $ = "dollar-sign"; console.log($); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ sign is an identifier for variables and functions. You can look at

http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign

Answer (score 0):

$ is used as a shortcut to access jQuery functions. jQuery is a library that simplifies working with the DOM, and many other things.

Answer (score 0):

$ is not a sign/symbol belongs to the javascript, its belong to some of its libraries, such as jQuery.

Have a look at [this](http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign) suggested in answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)