# In Javascript/JQuery what is $. for?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a utility file and I've gotten some examples from online and this a form of writing the utility I've come across:

```
$.util = $.extend($.util || {}, {

    //functions here...

});
```

and so I think I understand what it's doing. It allows me to call `$.util.function()` somewhere else, however when I remove the `.` in front of the `$` the code breaks. What does this notation mean? What's the difference between `$.` and `$`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette not quite the same

Comment: If you think of `$` as a synonym for `jQuery` then it becomes clear why "jQueryutil" doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.util = something` means "assign something to property `util` of object `$`".

`$util = something` means "assign something to variable `$util`"

Similarly, `$.extend` is "get value of property `extend` of object `$`" (which is a function in this exact scenario)  and `$extend` is "get value of variable `$extend`"

Comment: ohh shoot. I thought that adding `$` onto any variable would automatically make it jQuery. I'm not sure why I thought that but that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery, `$` is just a variable contaning the jQuery object. So by writing `$.`, you're essentially accessing jQuery properties and functions. Instead of `$`, you could also write `jQuery` and it should work the same way.

There's no special meaning to the `$` character in JavaScript other than that. It acts like any other character, so `$util` is just a variable name.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is an object that is assigned to both `jQuery` and `$` on the `window`

It has methods that act on collections of elements eg `$('.some-element').someMethod()` and static methods that are just attached to the jQuery object but don't modify a collection, They are just normal function attached to the jQuery object to prevent exposing too many functions to the global context.

Answer (score 2):

- `$.` - allows you to proceed to `$` (*`jQuery`*) object property or method directly
- `$` - usually used as shortcut for invoking jQuery object

Whilst prefixing anything with `$` won't make it jQueryable bec. this character can be used in variable name along with others (*e.g. what is not  applicable for PHP*).

Answer (score 2):

Consider jQuery as a big class woth a lot of static functions and constructs.

The right way for calling any of its functions should be `jQuery.someFunc()` for static functions and `var obj = jQuery('css selectors')` for creating an object for HTML objects and then executing functions on that object.

Now for easier coding, jQuery added `$` as an alias for `jQuery`. It's nothing more than an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('(jQuery === $) is ' + (jQuery === $) + '<br />');
    document.write('typeof(jQuery) = ' + typeof(jQuery) + '<br />');
  </script>
```

You will see:

> (jQuery === $) is true
>
> typeof(jQuery) = function

So jQuery is a function with a bunch of extra properties and functions attached to it.

If you're coming from a strongly-typed language background, the concept of attaching properties and methods to a function might seem strange, but you can do it in javascript.