# what does the function name starts with '$' mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It's not about jQuery.
When i read the source code of events.js in Node.js,i found that:

[image]

One of my guess is the function $getMaxListeners is used twice ,the second time it is used is after several lines.

i knew the '_' prefix is a convention which represents private.
so is there any convention of '$' prefix?

Comment: $ is just a character of the method's name in this case

Comment: It's just a character, no special meaning.

Comment: Seems to describe the pure `function` to be used on `prototype` here. For the `prototype` the version without `$` is used.

Comment: [_Certain frameworks and libraries have their own conventions on the meaning of the symbol_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/205974/2025923)

Comment: I've only ever seen the dollar prefix used for third-party libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery

Comment: @Tushar is there a case for this being a dupe?